# How to embed 3D models on a webpage?

Tags: aframe

We want to add to our website our 3D models and we copy an example from Aframe for testing
which worked ok:

https://madatac.es/31284-2/

```
<!-- wp:html -->
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
    init: function () {
      // Wait for model to load.
      this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
        // Grab the mesh / scene.
        const obj = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
        // Go over the submeshes and modify materials we want.
        obj.traverse(node => {
          if (node.name.indexOf('ship') !== -1) {
            node.material.color.set('red');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="cityModel" src="**https://cdn.aframe.io/test-models/models/glTF-2.0/virtualcity/VC.gltf**"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#cityModel" modify-materials=""></a-entity>
</a-scene>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

Then we wanted to try our own 3D gLTF model, stacked outside on our own personal server space, to see who it will work, but nothing appear...

```
<!-- wp:html -->
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('modify-materials', {
    init: function () {
      // Wait for model to load.
      this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
        // Grab the mesh / scene.
        const obj = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
        // Go over the submeshes and modify materials we want.
        obj.traverse(node => {
          if (node.name.indexOf('ship') !== -1) {
            node.material.color.set('red');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="cityModel" src="**https://madatac.es/contenidoweb/Sala 1.gltf**"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#cityModel" modify-materials=""></a-entity>
</a-scene>
<!-- /wp:html -->
```

Which can be the issue?

Do we have to stack the 3D gltf model on some Aframe assets place to getit viewed on our webpage?

Thanks in advance.

I.

Comment: Look for 404 errors on the browser network panel. Make sure your model is properly formed by loading it at https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: Also play with scale. Your model might be too big or too small

Comment: The GLTF viewer was of great help to solve this matter as it let us see that the first model was unfit, so we upload another one which works fine on our site.

Comment: You may also want to consider Google's `<model-viewer>` if your goal is to simply embed a 3D model and don't plan to use other A-Frame features, see https://modelviewer.dev/

Comment: Thank you mrossman. We used the code you linked  to embed it on our WP site, but only appears a blank window and not the astronaut. Any idea why this happens? Bests!